# 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in (Magento 2.1.6)

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute

This morning I tried to fix some Magento issues. Therefore I made some change on this files:

```
vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Session.php

app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml
```

As it didn't work, I changed all back to the original files. But I get this Errors on the product detail page now. How can I debug this issue?

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php on line 83

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php on line 83
#0 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php(83): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Array to string...', '/home/preview1/...', 83, Array)
#1 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml(19): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes->getAdditionalData()
#2 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/preview1/...')
#3 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes), '/home/preview1/...', Array)
#4 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/preview1/...')
#5 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#7 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('product.attribu...')
#8 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.attribu...')
#9 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml(16): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.attribu...')
#10 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/preview1/...')
#11 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description), '/home/preview1/...', Array)
#12 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/preview1/...')
#13 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#14 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#15 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('product.info.de...')
#16 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.de...')
#17 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.info.de...')
#18 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#19 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#20 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content')
#21 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main')
#22 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#23 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main')
#24 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns')
#25 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#26 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns')
#27 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content')
#28 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#29 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content')
#30 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#31 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#32 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#33 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#34 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#35 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root')
#36 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#37 /home/preview1/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#38 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(243): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#39 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#40 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#41 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#42 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'controller-resu...')
#43 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/litespeed/module-litemage/Model/Controller/Result/LitemagePlugin.php(71): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#44 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Litespeed\Litemage\Model\Controller\Result\LitemagePlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#45 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#46 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#47 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#48 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#49 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#50 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#51 /home/preview1/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#52 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#53 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#54 /home/preview1/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('launch', Array, Array)
#55 /home/preview1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#56 /home/preview1/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#57 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything inside var folder in magento root and then run static content deploy. you problem will be fix.